# Having getopts to show help if no options provided

Tags: bash, getopts

I parsed some similar questions posted here but they aren't suitable for me.

I've got this wonderful bash script which does some cool functions, here is the relevant section of the code:

```
while getopts ":hhelpf:d:c:" ARGS;
do
    case $ARGS in
        h|help )
            help_message >&2
            exit 1
            ;;
        f )
            F_FLAG=1
            LISTEXPORT=$OPTARG
            ;;
        d )
            D_FLAG=1
            OUTPUT=$OPTARG
            ;;
        c )
            CLUSTER=$OPTARG
            ;;
        \? )
            echo ""
            echo "Unimplemented option: -$OPTARG" >&2
            echo ""
            exit 1
            ;;
        : )
            echo ""
            echo "Option -$OPTARG needs an argument." >&2
            echo ""
            exit 1
            ;;
        * )
            help_message >&2
            exit 1
            ;;
    esac
done
```

Now, all my options works well, if triggered. What I want is getopts to spit out the *help_message function* when no option is triggered, say the script is launched just **./scriptname.sh** without arguments.

I saw some ways posted here, implementing **IF** cycle and **functions** but, since I'm just starting with bash and I already have some IF cycles on this script, I would like to know if there is an easier (and pretty) way to to this.

Comment: I don't think `help` in that `getopts` string is doing what you are expecting it to do. `getopts`doesn't do long options. That should be adding options for `e`, `l`, and `p` to that call.

Comment: That `help` is working properly.

Comment: Are you *sure* about that? What are you testing to see that? Stick an `echo case h` in the `h|help` case block and an `echo 'case *'` in the `*` case and then try `script --help` (and then `script -l`) and see what you get. Also `script --help` (which would be the long-option version).

Comment: I saw what you are talking about, but I just did it and it works. I can call the script passing -h or -help, and it works.

Comment: Neither of those is what I told you to test. Do the things I actually told you to test and see what output you get from those added `echo` lines. You will not get the cases you expect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Many thanks to Etan Reisner, I ended up using your suggestion:

```
if [ $# -eq 0 ];
then
    help_message
    exit 0
else
...... remainder of script
```

This works exactly the way I supposed. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

If you just want to detect the script being called with no options then just check the value of `$#` in your script and exit with a message when it is zero.

If you want to catch the case where no option arguments are passed (but non-option arguments) are still passed then you should be able to check the value of `OPTIND` after the `getopts` loop and exit when it is 1 (indicating that the first argument is a non-option argument).

Answer (score 0):

Dropping a sample code from @Etan Reisner's statement:

> you want to catch the case where no option arguments are passed (but non-option arguments) are still passed then you should be able to check the value of OPTIND after the getopts loop and exit when it is 1 (indicating that the first argument is a non-option argument).

```
# Check if any arguments were passed
if [ $OPTIND -eq 1 ]; then
    help_message
    exit 1
fi 
# ........ the rest of the script
```

Just in case someone wanted a sample visual