# How can I use getOpt to determine if no options are given in C?

Tags: c, command-line, arguments, command-line-arguments, getopt

I'm working on a simple program that supposed to change a string to all uppercase or all lowercase depending on the arguments. For example, if the executable's name is `change` :

> ./change -u thiswillbeuppercase
>
> THISWILLBEUPPERCASE
>
> ./change -l THISWILLBELOWERCASE
>
> thiswillbelowercase

The issue im having if that i cannot figure out how to perform the uppercase action by default, if no options are provided. For example, this is how i would like it to perform:

> ./change thiswillbeuppercase
>
> THISWILLBEUPPERCASE

Here is what my main function looks like currently:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
int c;
while((c = getopt(argc,argv,"u:s:l:")) != -1){
    char *str = optarg;
    if(c == '?'){
        c = optopt;
        printf("Illegal option %c\n",c);
    } else{
    
        switch(c){
            case 'u':
                strupper(str);
                break;
            case 'l':
                strlower(str);
                break;
            case 's':
                strswitch(str);
                break;
            default:
                strupper(str);
                break;
    
        }
    }

}
return 0;
```

}

I tried calling the strupper function in the default part of the switch statement but that doesn't seem to work. As of now the program does nothing when  provided with no options.

I search stackoverflow for similar questions and i found someone with the [same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26592217/having-getopts-to-show-help-if-no-options-provided), but their question is related to bash and not C.

If anyone has any advice i would really appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: Either your question title is misleading or I don't understand what you're asking in the body of the question

Comment: The second yellow box is the functionality i am trying to create. If the user inputs no options, it will call the strupper function by default. Sorry if i wasn't clear on that.

Comment: Why didn't you put your `if (c == '?')` case in the `switch` statement?

Comment: Why not just set a variable representing the action you want, initialized to some default action?  Am I overlooking something?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. I'm really new to c and the getopt documentation didn't help me very much. I just want to be able to call the strupper function if there's no options.

Comment: You need to grab the so-called nonopts that are saved at the end when you use getopt_long.  See the example on this page: http://linux.die.net/man/3/getopt_long

Comment: The `default:` in your switch statement is executed if the character `c` doesn't match any of the above cases.  This has nothing to do with "default action" if no options are given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would change your code this way:

```
... several includes here...
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int c;
    while((c = getopt(argc,argv,"u:s:l:")) != -1){
    // ... no changes here ...   
    }
    if ( ( argc > 1 ) && ( c == (-1) ) ) { 
        // implement your default action here. Example
        // for ( int i = 1 ; i < argc ; i++ ) {
        //    strupper ( argv[i] ) ;
        // }
    } 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: this would be good since getopt (and getopt_long) both strip off the argv array and decrement the argc count as you iterate through the options.

Answer (score 0):

use `#include <bits/getopt_core.h>`